# In GitAhead, is there a way to delete a remote branch when I already deleted the corresponding local branch?

Tags: gitahead

I've already deleted a local branch without deleting its upstream branch on a GitHub.
Is there a way to delete the remote branch in a GitAhead?

In Sourcetree you just right click on the remote branch and choose *delete*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, GitAhead doesn't have an easy way to push a delete except for the little convenience checkmark when you delete the local branch. You would have to resort to the command line or doing it on your remote host.

Comment: Or you can create the local branch again and the delete both.

Answer (score 0):

This is a major design flaw in Git (in my opinion). The branching concept in mercurial is much more sane (no detached heads, named branches, no ability to delete branches - at least not if it was published once).

think about it: it is a versioning control system. What you want is to preserve and document development history. Someone has created and published a branch for purpose. So even if git allows manipulation of the repository much more than mercurial (and here most abilities are disabled by default!), just do not use it. leave the branch! Its OK. Its the way it should be. Anyway, as git is lean here, its just a pointer (not a real named branch like in hg), it does not take much  space.